# What happens to customers with old phones if you upload a new app revision with a stricter filter?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to update my app to require OpenGL ES 2.0. But I want the old version to remain downloadable for my customers that have phones that support only ES 1.0.

If my new revision of the app has

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

in its manifest, what will customers with older phones see when they go to update the app? Will they be able to download the older revision, or does it just say their phone can't run the app and they're out of luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they want be able to see the app at all in the Market/Play Store. You should upload multiple APKs with different versions, to make sure older devices can still see (the older version of) your app. Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that method won't work for the glEsVersion filter. Advanced mode only compares the filters for screen size, API level, and texture compression method, so if the only difference is the glEsVersion filter, it won't let you activate the two different APKs at once.

Comment: Right, the whole multiple APK thing is somewhat limited. There was some talk that users will see the last published version, compatible with their device, but that was before multiple APKs, so I guess it's been removed (if it ever worked that way). Your best bet is probably to publish a dummy app and check for yourself.